# convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, radicals

> I'm studying the convergence of the series
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}}$$

- $\frac {\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}}>0, \forall n \ge 1$
- $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac {\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac {n^2+1-n^2}{\sqrt{n}*(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n)}=0$
- The suggested solution in my book says that the series converges but:
  $\frac {\frac {\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}}}{(\frac {1}{n})^{- \frac {1}{2}}}= \frac {n* \sqrt {1+ \frac {1}{n^2}}}{ \sqrt {n}}* \frac {1}{\sqrt {n}}    \rightarrow 1 $ for $n \rightarrow \infty $

Comment: Anne, a friendly advice: try to work on you assignments a bit more on your own before asking for help here. This is not the first question of yours which can be solved by applying an elementary inequality, and you will find out that many problems in Calculus can be tackled through the same "trick". $$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\left(n+\sqrt{n^2+1}\right)}\approx\frac{1}{2n^{3/2}}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n)}<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n^3}}$$ and since $\frac{3}{2}>1$ it converges.

Because
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}}<\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n^3}}$$ and since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n^3}}$ converges, we are done.

Comment: What I don't understand is why $ \sqrt {n^2+1}+n \sim 2n$

Comment: $\sqrt{n^2+1}+n=n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}+1\right)\sim2n$ and $n\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{n^3}$.

Comment: why 2? .................

Comment: Because $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}+1\rightarrow2$ for $n\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: thanks Michael Rozemberg

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$ \frac {\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \frac { \sqrt{n^2+1}+n }{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}= \frac { 1 }{\sqrt{n^3+n}+n\sqrt n}\sim \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n^3}}$$

thus

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac { 1 }{\sqrt{n^3+n}+n\sqrt n}$$

converges by comparison test with $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3}}$$